# Etymology of the word "stofen" (and other names for the same thing)

Tags: flash, terminology, diffusers

Does anyone know the origin of the the word "stofen" and its correct — or at least accepted — spelling?  I've seen it spelt "stofen" (which seems to be the most frequent variant), "Stofen", and "Sto-Fen".  By stofen I mean the translucent, white, plastic diffusion "cups" that press on to the head of a portable flash.

Although, it seems to me most people use the word "stofen", perhaps it isn't the name most people use.  The American company Sto-Fen, offer a "stofen" they market as the Omni-Bounce.  And I've seen the word "softy" used and also "diffusion dome" — which, I think is used improperly as the things are rectangular in shape and not domed.

If "stofen" is the canonical form, did the word derived from the name of the Sto-Fen company?  And, if so, was it because they invented the "stofen", or simply popularised something that was already in use?

Comment: I guess I'll have to stop calling it a Fonger now that you've introduced me to the proper name...nope, it'll always be a Fonger :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am quite certain that "Sto-Fen" is just the name of one company.

As you note, that company doesn't call their product a "stofen" — they call it the "Omni-Bounce". I don't find any evidence for any prior generic use of the Sto-Fen name *anywhere* — or for that matter, much use *today*. If you do a Google Books search, you only get references to this product from the same company, going back to the late 1970s / early 1980s. If it were a previously-used term, you'd see it show up (as for example "[speedlite](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60702/whats-the-generic-term-for-portable-flashes-speedlites-speedlights-etc/60711#60711)" does).

The [trademark](https://trademarks.justia.com/853/84/sto-fen-85384039.html) for "STO-FEN" was only filed in 2011, but notes May 31, 1979 as the first use in commerce — presumably before then, it was ™ rather than ®. Crucially for the etymology question, though, the registrant is *Ernest C. Fenn*. Presumably, the last part of the company name comes from this last name.

The general name of such a device is "push-on diffuser" — "diffusion dome" is also common, even when the shape isn't actually a dome. (See for example the [SW-14H Diffusion Dome](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/flash-diffusers/sw-14h-diffusion-dome.html) from Nikon.)

Answer (score 0):

> Etymology of the word “stofen"?

I hope this isn't too much of a stretch (pun intended) unlike the [Stofen company](http://www.stofen.com/info/index.asp) some [flash diffusers](http://www.phottix.com/index.php/en/phottix-cloth-soft-flash-diffuser.html) are made of cloth. [German](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Stoff#German): cloth, fabric, material **or** [Dutch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stoffen): fabric (made of fabric).