# How do I use Canon speedlights off-camera with a Sony A7 III?

Tags: off-camera-flash, sony-alpha

I'm currently in the limbo phase of converting my system to Sony…but meanwhile I need to work with my current collection of Canon speedlights.  I'm having trouble understanding exactly which trigger system to purchase that can allow off-camera use of my Canon speedlights from my Sony A7iii camera bodies. The Godox system looks decent and affordable, but I can't find a definite answer on whether or not the receivers are camera-specific or strobe-specific.

For example, I'd be getting the Godox XPro-S transmitter, but for the receivers do I get the X1R-S (for Sony "cameras") or the X1R-C (for Canon "cameras") since I know that the hotshoes are different for Canon and Sony specific strobes? Or does that not matter? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What Canon units do you have?  They might be worth keeping even without HSS or TTL metering.

Answer (score 2):

The only triggering system where you can use legacy OEM TTL speedlights cross-brand is the [Cactus V6II X-TTL](https://www.cactus-image.com/special/X-TTL/) system. However, [Cactus may be  out of the photographic gear business](https://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/125-flashes-lighting-studio/417423-message-cactus.html). And the entire system consists of the transceivers and two single-pin speedlights that cannot do TTL/HSS on any camera hotshoe; they can only do TTL/HSS as off-camera radio slaves. There are no larger lights in the system.

Godox does **not** allow you to use legacy OEM TTL speedlights cross-brand with TTL and HSS. The X1R receiver is dedicated to a single brand, and only delivers TTL/HSS with a same-brand camera, transmitter, and flash.

So, for example, you can only get TTL/HSS with a Godox XPro-C on a Canon camera hotshoe, with a 580EX II on an X1R-C.  Trying to use an XPro-S on a Sony camera hotshoe with the X1R-C would be manual communication. You would definitely have sync, and you'd probably have group on/off control, but remote power control, TTL, and HSS are improbable (I've seen various conflicting reports of what function you would have).

The X1R-S would be if you were using a Sony HVL speedlight with an XPro-S on a Sony camera hotshoe.

What *is* cross-brand in the Godox system are the transceivers or receivers built into Godox strobes. So, if, for example, you had gotten a Godox TT685-C as your Canon speedlight, that could be used as a TTL/HSS radio slave to an XPro-S on your Sony camera.  I use a TT685-C that way with an XPro-C on my Canon 5DMkII, an XPro-F on my Fuji X100T, and an XPro-O on my Panasonic GX7:

[image: LCD screen of TT685-C used from -C, -F, and -O transmitters]

Whatever goes directly on the hotshoe of the camera (transmitter, speedlight) has to match the brand of the camera, though.

Generally with Godox, it's a matter of swapping your legacy flashes for Godox lights.  It may be best to sell your Canon flash gear, and get Godox gear for Sony instead.

Comment: Nothing unique about Cactus, everyone might be getting out of the photographic gear business. Even Olympus. If it works, it works. Of course everyone's definition of "works" varies.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens, I was going on [something a little more solid and immediate](https://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/125-flashes-lighting-studio/417423-message-cactus.html), but since Cactus themselves haven't formally announced it, and you can still buy the V6IIs, I used the subjunctive.

Comment: Thanks. That looks like it.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens. No worries. I've edited my statement to be a bit stronger with a direct link to that post.

Comment: Isn't Speedlight a Nikon brand name? Not a term I ever use. Shouldn't we just call a flash unit a "flash (unit)"? Kinda like calling every instant picture a "Polaroid". Possibly it's a British English / American English thing.

Comment: Nikon called them 'Speedlights', Canon called them 'Speedlites', as did Ricoh (Pentax), but apparently no one ever applied for intellectual property rights on either term. It's all covered in [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/60711/15871) here at Photo SE.

Comment: @inkista well, it's not just for me. You corrected terminology. It's good for everyone. As I said, I think it's possibly a British English / American English thing. I've actually never heard anyone use the term speedlight here. There is more to the world of photography, stack exchange and the Internet in general than America ‍♂️